# Android grpc error: TLS ALPN negotiation failed with protocols: [grpc-exp, h2]

Tags: android, grpc, tls1.2, alpn

I'm trying to use grpc in an Android App

The important part of the code is this:

```
private val managedChannel: ManagedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder
        .forTarget("misserverurl.com")
        .build()
```

build.gradle with version and dependencies:

```
minSdkVersion 19

implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.26.0"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.26.0"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.26.0"
```

The protos seems okay, and the app works without TLS (**.usePlaintext()**)

But I'm getting this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: TLS ALPN negotiation failed with protocols: [grpc-exp, h2]`

Where it seems there is a problem with the **SSL handshake**.

The weird part is that the server works using BloomRCP using TLS.

I've tried with different minSdkVersions, also using different io.grpc.* lib versions and creating an empty repo with just the proto files and the basic code to run it but nothing and adding .connectionSpec() with different CipherSuite as well.

Using Wireshark I could see that the TLS version that I'm sending is 1.2 which is correct and expected (maybe it's not using HTTP2?)

Any guest?
Thanks in advance!

--------------------------------------------------- Edit ---------------------------------------------------

Look into the lib I've found this method: **useTransportSecurity()**

```
/**
* Sets the negotiation type for the HTTP/2 connection to TLS (this is the default).
...
*/
@Override
public final OkHttpChannelBuilder useTransportSecurity() { ... }
```

We are using TLS with HTTP/2 by default, so that's not the problem...

Answer (score 1):

HTTP/2 is negotiated during TLS using ALPN. The client sends what protocols it supports (in this case grpc-exp and h2, aka http/2). The server then selects what protocol, or none. If none is selected then the only options are to fall back to another protocol like HTTP/1 or to fail.

gRPC requires HTTP/2, so the server must select 'h2' via ALPN. The error is that didn't happen. Your server needs to support HTTP/2. If you are using a TLS terminator or you are using an L7 load balancer, you must configure it to support HTTP/2.

Comment: But is it possible that https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java whose default config is to use TLS don't do the request over HTTP/2? If that's the case, how do I set it up?
Not sure if h2 is the problem, but don't know why it's accepting BloomRPC request but no GRPC-JAVA's

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this issue before when using java 1.8.0_242-b08, after upgrade to 1.8.0_265, no issue

Comment: I can confirm that specific Java versions might also cause the issue. In my case the problem was with java version 1.8.0_352

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was a backend issue.
Following this: https://www.getambassador.io/reference/core/tls/#alpn_protocols
The alpn_protocol was set like this:

`alpn_protocol = h2[, grpc-epx]`

Where it should be:

`alpn_protocol = h2`

With that and this config in client side, it worked!

```
private val managedChannel: ManagedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder
        .forTarget("misserverurl.com")
        .build()
```